# CSS , Bootstrap : only the navbar-wrapper transparent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I make the menu bar background transparent but still the text on the menu bar NOT transparent?

This is twitter bootstrap carousel template.

And in this line,

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.701961); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; opacity: 0.2;">
```

I want BACKGROUND-ONLY transparent so that other images in my pages can be shown with the transparent layout.

I did similar thing with    div#bg:after  for the whole background but for bootstrap I have no idea how I make this happen.

Following is my code.

Thanks in advance!

```
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.701961); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; opacity: 0.2;">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <!-- toggle menu for mobile page -->
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#buy" target="_blank"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-0.25"></i>&thinsp; &thinsp; Buy Now</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://abc.com"> abc</a>
                    </div>


                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active" ><a href="http://abc.com">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">Products</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Connect</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Get Some</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-large"></i>&thinsp; Buy Now <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">Payment Option</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Paypal.com</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Amazon.com</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Perhaps try removing the opacity setting? Example: http://jsbin.com/iJuwEHi/1/

Comment: opacity is not required as you have used background-color:rgba() already..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example may help you to get what you want.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXN7U/)

```
div.background
  {
  width:500px;
  height:250px;
  background:url(klematis.jpg) repeat;
  border:2px solid black;
  }
div.transbox
  {
  width:400px;
  height:180px;
  margin:30px 50px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid black;
  opacity:0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  }
```

Comment: It is not working in CSS bootstrap because I do not have background image for bootstrap wrapper. Could you be more specific on Boostrap?

Answer (score 0):

just use this instead of your code

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; ">
```